# XenServer bad network config during initial Pool Creation

Tags: ip, xenserver, pool

I believe I made a terrible mistake.

I had a XEN8.0 (Citrix Hypervisor) for tests running on a local machine here in the office. It has a local IP adress. Classic.

Then I wanted to move my VM guests to a dedicated server in the cloud. XEN installed, configured, cool.

Then, the transfer with in/export function in XenCenter of a guest was not working. Then I choose to create a pool, because I thought, that I simply can move the guest systems to the other server. You might know what happens.

Situation now:

XEN_1 in cloud, master, public accessible IP (new)

XEN_2 local, slave, local IP behind router (old)

```
XEN_1# xe pool-sync-database
You attempted an operation which involves a host which could not be contacted.
```

---

```
XEN_2# xe pif-list
The master reports that it cannot talk back to the slave on the supplied management IP address.
ip: 192.168.103.81

XEN_2# xe pif-list params=uuid,host-name-label,device,management
The host toolstack is still initialising. Please wait.
```

I assume, XEN_2 tells XEN_1 his IP which is not reachable for him and the so it's a deadlock situation.

Question: Is it possible to tell XEN_1 somehow the IP of my local router?

The very bad thing is, that the Local Storage of XEN_2 is not accessible and there is one guest system which has very very important content. So vanishing the whole system is not a real option.

Other Question: Is it possible to access guest data via SSH?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking further you are having issues with network connectivity since XEN_2 local is not having static IP address.  You can have a  VPN solution and add both Citrix Xen servers with private networks in order to migrate the VM from the same pool.

Comment: Perfect. At first I have not believed in this solution, but actually it worked. It was a bit of a mess to establish the VPN connection as `vpnc` had to be compiled manually. Find details [here](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/407119-bad-network-config-during-initial-pool-creation/).